# Как грузить данные для одного класса?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

по клику грузятся данные Json, и вставляются в качестве Input

```js
$('.editReviewAjax').click(function(){
   postId = $(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://reviews2.ru/review/'+postId+'/edit',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $('.reviewBody').text('<input type="text" value="'+data.body+'">');
    }
   })
});
```

```html
<div class="reviewView">
                <div>
                 <span class="reviewTitle">{{ $review->title }} || <a href="#" onclick="return false;" id="{{ $review->id }}" class="editReviewAjax">
.....+++(Остальные элементы)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.editReviewAjax').click(function(){
  postId = $(this).attr('id');
  var parent = $(this).closest('.reviewBody');
  $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://reviews2.ru/review/'+postId+'/edit',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        parent.text('<input type="text" value="'+data.body+'">');
    }
  })
});
```

Ну и наверное не `parent.text(`, а `parent.html(`.

Comment: Благодарю, практически то)
Вот только, с .reviewBody не работает, если указываю класс reviewView (див с новостями), то все хорошо(правда, меняется весь вид конкретной статьи).
И еще, таких полей 3, как можно реализовать корректную работу?

Comment: @DeadMoras по содержимому Вашего вопроса невозможно сказать какой класс Вам в действительности нужен. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос с указанием текущего поведения и желательного поведения.

Comment: Родительский класс .reviewView.
В нем находятся классы, reviewBody - в том числе.
Этот класс отвечает за внешний вид каждой статьи.
Кроме reviewBody у меня еще 2 инпута(название статьи и категории).